# how do async/await testing with TypeScript and mocha

Tags: typescript, async-await, mocha.js

I have a simple async mocha test, but the `done()` callback never seems to get called.

```
describe("RiBot", function() {
  it("should start with a random topic", async (done) => {
    await RiBot.init();
    let topic = RiBot.getTopic("testuser")
    assert.equal(topic, "FAILHERE");
    done()
  })
})
```

In this case the assertion should fail but instead I just get a timeout.

```
  RiBot
  RibotTest topic +0ms undefined
    1) should start with a random topic


  0 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) RiBot should start with a random topic:
     Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

edit: when i run just as standard JS code with an assert:

```
async function testRiBot() {
  try {
    await RiBot.init()
    let topic = RiBot.getTopic("testuser")
    debug('topic', topic)
    assert.equal(topic, "FAILHERE", 'fail match on topic');
  } catch(err) {
    debug("err", err, err.stack)
  }
}
```

I do get an exception thrown as the error.

```
  RibotTest err +2ms { [AssertionError: fail match on topic]
  name: 'AssertionError',
  actual: 'undefined',
  expected: 'FAILHERE',
  operator: '==',
  message: 'fail match on topic',
  generatedMessage: false } AssertionError: fail match on topic
    at /Users/dc/dev/rikai/boteditor/test/RiBot_test.js:19:20
    at next (native)
    at fulfilled (/Users/dc/dev/rikai/boteditor/test/RiBot_test.js:4:58)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:412:9)
```

Can someone provide a simple example using a typescript async/await and mocha?

Answer (score 10):

Try defining your test like this... (and at the same time remove your *done* call)

```
it('should start with a random topic', async function () {
    // ...
});
```

Note if your test returns a Promise then the mocha framework will look for the Promise to be resolved or rejected rather than a done callback. Note async functions always return a Promise.

Also it's a best practice to avoid using arrow functions to define tests otherwise you can't access the correct `this` context from the test (i.e. you can't do things like calling `this.title` within your test code).